# Batch Insert performance comparison of MongoDB and Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, mongodb, bulkinsert

Has anyone done batch insert comparison between MongoDB vs Sql Server ?

If yes, which one performed better? if not, i ll do it :)

I m very curious about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples to Oranges. Basically you're asking to compare the speed of writing in memory vs. the speed of writing to disk. MongoDB durability model is a moving target, but as a rule the NoSQL databases don't value local durability very much, eg. [What about Durability?](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/381927266/what-about-durability). With v1.7.5 MongoDB supports WAL [jurnaling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling), but the Mongo commit is not flushing the WAL. To have an equivalent comparison of similar behavior you would have to issue [`getLastError()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) after each MongoDB commit, which would be the closest equivalent of relational transaction commit. But then one would have to ask what are you using [quorums](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/475279604/on-distributed-consistency-part-1) for? No matter how you slice it, it will still be Apples and Oranges.